# Gerrit mistakenly deleted tables Any solution?

Tags: gerrit

i have accidentally deleted data from table account_external_ids. Now my gerrit is in unstable position. There is no more administrator in it. now i can not open gsql as i don't have any user with "access database" privilege. what should i do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `auth.type = DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT` in `etc/gerrit.conf`, this is a setting designed for development where you can just add new accounts. See [docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_auth_a_section_auth).

Comment: Did this work for you? If yes, I would delete my other answer.

Comment: thanks alot stephen m able to create new admin users which are authenticated from ldap :)